# Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) even when deleting derived data

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Can't seem to get rid of this error. Here is a snippet of the error I get:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFHTTPSessionManager._requestSerializer in:
    /Users/dhawalsoni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/kyss3-easouczitnxpphdviuuiqyfnjomw/Build/Intermediates/kyss3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/kyss3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AFHTTPSessionManager.o
    /Users/dhawalsoni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/kyss3-easouczitnxpphdviuuiqyfnjomw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libAFNetworking.a(AFHTTPSessionManager.o)
```

Here are the pods I am using:
    pod 'Parse'
    pod 'GooglePlaces'
    pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'
    #pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.3.3'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'

Answer (score 0):

Check which option helps you.
1.  have you included the .h file and the .m file twice in the project and compile it. if yes then remove the second copy.
2.  have you included .m file instead of .h file
3.  clean your project

Comment: I am using cocoa pods and I have imported UIKit+AFNetworking and AFNetworking files into my project. I don't see any duplicate files.